# Calculated Field Help. Get percentage of how many underweight trucks there are

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I am doing a project and I am supposed to get the percentages of trucks that are under weight (under 25k lbs) by using only a pivot table. I am not allowed to touch or add anything to the data at all. I have the count of how many trucks are under weights, I just do not know how to get the total percentage. I cannot add anything to the data. My only hint was that I need to use calculated field.

This is what I have so far: This data has been filtered and what seems like I need to do is take the filtered data and divide it with the unfiltered data. Please Help

Comment: Calculate the percentage based on the total number of trucks.

Answer (score 0):

In the “value field settings” you can choose how to show the values as … % of different totals

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-different-calculations-in-pivottable-value-fields-014d2777-baaf-480b-a32b-98431f48bfec